# Using an RCD with an isolation transformer for an electrical pig stunner

Tags: transformer, isolation, rcd

Someone asked me to build an electrical pig stunner. I will make it simple as in the schematic attached. Even I'll put an isolation transformer I would like to take extra safety measures and place and 30mA RCD on the 230V input.
Question: when this will be used, meaning that the 2 electrodes will be placed on the pig's either side's head, will the RCD trip ?

[image]

Comment: I don't think building such a thing is the province of a hobbyist. Downvoting this for removal.

Comment: This will probably make the pig very mad and the person applying this will be stunned when the pig attacks them.

Comment: This is *not* how a 'pig stunner' is made. This is cruel & inhumane (and yes bacon is delicious and I'm not a rabid vegan PETA activist). Do some research into how these devices are commercially designed & constructed and don't subject animals to torture, even if they are about to be slaughtered (it just ruins the meat anyway).

Comment: How do we know if you are planning to use this on a pig or a human... regardless of that, the intention sounds malicious. Hence, discouraging the question on this platform.

Comment: @brhans  [Here](https://i.imgur.com/GRkKjma.png) is the schematic of a US-manufactured stunner. And [how it is used](https://i.imgur.com/EdfKuJs.png). The black disks are star wheel spurs. Just a fixed selectable AC voltage with a timeout of up to 9 seconds. Barbaric.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I guess here in the land of the free the USDA just doesn't care (at least not enough to turn down the lobbyists cash anyway). Hopefully it's a little more civilized your side of the border. I can't imagine that kind of thing being regarded as legal by the Dept of Agriculture back home in darkest Africa ...

Comment: @brhans I just got through reading Upton Sinclair's classic book *Jungle* on the brutal lives of immigrants in the Chicago packing district ca. 1900. We've at least progressed significantly from there, for people and for the animals (and the now-inspected products made from them), even allowing for some license on the author's part.

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of when they tried to get UL approval for an electric chair. Controlled current is recommended to get reliable inducement of grand mal seizure and sufficient seconds of unconsciousness for the hapless animal to be hoisted and bled. Otherwise it's not as reliable and also has to be adjusted for the size of the beast.

In any case, normally it might trigger the RCD since this sort of thing is typically carried out in an environment with wet floors (and the animal's head is wet for conductivity) and there may well therefore be paths to ground, except you have the RCD on the other side of an isolation transformer so the RCD will do nothing at all of value.